# Accept Cookies from One Website only : PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I was wondering if there was a way in PHP to accept cookies from only the original website.

For Example:

I set a cook when a visitor come to my website www.example.com, now when they come from a website like Microsoft Translator to view my website that cookie is set with the web address of Microsoft. I then only want to get cookies from my website example.com and not allow the cookie to work if visiting my site through Microsoft Translator.

I hope this make sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You're misunderstanding how cookies work - cookies are ALWAYS set only for the domain from which they originate. It's a violation of the cookie spec to allow a site to set a cookie for a domain other than itself - think of what would happen if "nastysite.com" were able to set a cookie for "yourbank.com"?

Perhaps you're thinking of the REFERER, which (if it's available) can point back to the address of the page the user came from.

However, that can't affect the cookies on your site, unless you yourself are placing any of that referer information into the cookie. If you don't want users who came in from Microsoft Translator to get a cookie, then you have to check the REFERER and simply not set the cookie if they did.